# Is it possible to limit a loop in dust.js without using extensions / custom helpers?

Tags: dust.js

I'm using dust.js templates under the LinkedIn fork and Python 'Ashes' implementation.

In a given situation, I have 15 elements in an array.  I want to only loop through the first 5 elements.

Does anyone know of a way to structure a template in dust to achieve this without writing helpers -- I'd like to keep the templates working similarly on JS and Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few tools available to you, but your options for maintaining cross-compat between Dust and Ashes are going to force compromises.

Ashes has some of the basic logic helpers found in `dust-helpers` available, like `{@eq}` and `{@lt}`, so I'll assume that you can import that library for Dust as well.

In Dust, the easiest way to do this would be:

```
{#items}
  {@lt key=$idx value=5}{! output the item info !}{/lt}
{/items}
```

Dust will iterate over the whole list, but will only output items with an index less than 5.

Ashes, as you've seen from [your opened issue](https://github.com/mahmoud/ashes/issues/23), doesn't support `$idx`, but only the helper form `{@idx/}`-- and you can't use helpers as comparators inside another helper like `{@lt}`.

So your options are limited. If you can, the best option would be to add an `index` property to the objects in your array. Hopefully this is as simple as something like:

```
return items.map((item, idx) => { item.idx = idx; return item });
```

Then you could write the same template as above, but use the key on your `item`:

```
{#items}
  {@lt key=idx value=5}{! item info woooo !}{/lt}
{/items}
```

If you have no API access, the next-best option is probably using partial contexts, which are supported by Ashes.

```
{> itemTemplate:item[0] /}
{> itemTemplate:item[1] /}
{> itemTemplate:item[2] /}
{> itemTemplate:item[3] /}
{> itemTemplate:item[4] /}
```

In this example, the context of the partial will be set to one item at a time. Much more succinct than pasting the contents of your loop five times.

Comment: Thanks.  I think the easiest solution would be patching ashes to have the `$idx` and then using `@lt`.  I've submitted a few patches for them before, so this might be the best option. There are too many data sources for arrays I need to limit, and only a handful of templates, so adding an `.idx` property would actually require a lot of work and unit tests.